# Xamarin.ios on premise Build Failes on VSTS with return code 1

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are trying to create a build definition for xamarin.ios and we have a on premise build agent, we have syncfusion references included in the project, getting a error while the build is running.
[image: here is the issue which we get]

Comment: What're steps of your build definition? Can you restore, build your project on your build agent manually? On the other hand, try to set system.debug to true (variables tab) and queue build to check whether there is detail error message. Try to refer to this article to build xamarin.iso: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/mobile/xamarin

Comment: @starain-MSFT I tried to follow the same link, but my problem here is there are two sources for nuget one is coming from nuget.org and other is syncfusion libraries which is coming from syncfusion.nuget.org and this is what failing in the build definition, my actual concern is how do we upload this packages manually or configure the source on VSTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is that you can add `nuget.config` file to source control and specify it for `NuGet restore` step/task (Path to NuGet.config)

Another way is that, you can add Command Line step/task to add sources (Tool: [nuget.exe path (include nuget.exe to source control and map to build agent)], Arguments: `sources add [name] -Source [feed address] -username [user name] -password [password] -StorePasswordInClearText`